# template function name as template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I defined some template functions like:

```
template<unsigned char V>
void print(){
    std::cout << (int)V << std::endl;
}
```

Now I want create const arrays of function pointers. I tried to use C++11 variadic template to construct these arrays:

```
template<typename Type, Type... args>
struct Combination{
    const static Type data[sizeof...(args)];
};

template<typename Type, Type... args>
const Type Combination<Type, args...>::data[sizeof...(args)] = {args...};

template<typename Type, unsigned char var, Type... args>
struct FunArray{
    typedef
    typename FunArray<Type, var-1, &print<var-1>, args...>::result
        result;
};

template<typename Type, Type... args>
struct FunArray<Type, (unsigned char)0, args...>{
    typedef Combination<Type, args...> result;
};
```

And the solution works perfectly.

```
int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        FunArray<void(*)(), 8>::result::data[i]();
}
```

The main function will print a list from 0 to 7.

Now my question is, I have some other template function and I want to write a set of template tools to generate an array for each of these functions like this. So I need to use a parameter to replace hard-coded function name in the template. However, the following code won't compile:

```
template<typename Type, Type... args>
struct Combination{
    const static Type data[sizeof...(args)];
};

template<typename Type, Type... args>
const Type Combination<Type, args...>::data[sizeof...(args)] = {args...};

template<typename Type, typename Fun, unsigned char var, Type... args>
struct FunArray{
    typedef
    typename FunArray<Type, Fun, var-1, &Fun<var-1>, args...>::result
        result;
};

template<typename Type, typename Fun, Type... args>
struct FunArray<Type, Fun, (unsigned char)0, args...>{
    typedef Combination<Type, args...> result;
};
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: You can use a function object type instead of a function. There are template *template-parameters* in C++ (= pass a template), but only for class templates, not for function templates (and you can't pass a name as a template-argument directly).

Comment: Another way is to pass a function object type (as an argument for a type template-parameter) that has a static member function template. Then you don't have to deal with template *template-parameters*, but need to use the `template` keyword for syntax disambiguation.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.  The trick is (a) to use struct template wrappers (`print` and `otherPrint`) instead of direct function templates, and (b) to use template template parameters.  (I must confess that I find some of the restrictions of C++11 very counter-intuitive, e.g., it would have been nice to use a template alias in the template parameter for `FunArray`.)

```
template<unsigned char V>                                                       
struct print{                                                                   
  static void call () { std::cout << (int)V << std::endl; }                     
};                                                                              

template<unsigned char V>                                                       
struct otherPrint{                                                              
  static void call () { std::cout << (char)('a'+V) << std::endl; }              
};                                                                              

template<typename Type, Type... args>                                           
struct Combination{                                                             
  const static Type data[sizeof...(args)];                                      
};                                                                              

template<typename Type, Type... args>                                           
const Type Combination<Type, args...>::data[sizeof...(args)] = {args...};       

template<typename Type, template<unsigned char V> class Fun,                    
         unsigned char var, Type... args>                                       
struct FunArray{                                                                
    typedef                                                                     
    typename FunArray<Type, Fun, var-1, Fun<var-1>::call, args...>::result      
    result;                                                                     
};                                                                              

template<typename Type, template<unsigned char V> class Fun, Type... args>      
struct FunArray<Type, Fun, (unsigned char)0, args...>{                          
  typedef Combination<Type, args...> result;                                    
};

int main() {                                                                    
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)                                                    
    FunArray<void(*)(), print, 8>::result::data[i]();                           
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)                                                    
    FunArray<void(*)(), otherPrint, 8>::result::data[i]();                      
  return 0;                                                                     
}
```